# Prove there generally is no isomorphism between $R[x]/(x^2-a)$ and $R^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

I have a ring $\mathbf R =(R, +, -, ., 0, 1)$ (note that there is no invers for multiplication, $R$ is not $\mathbb R$, it is any set for the given algebra).

How do you prove that the following does not apply generally (meaning for all $a \in R$)?

$$\mathbf R[x]/(x^2−a)\mathbf R[x] \simeq \mathbf R^2$$

I know that the following does apply:  $\mathbf R[x]/(x−a)\mathbf R[x] \simeq \mathbf R$ , you can prove that using the first isomorphism theorem by finiding a homomorphism by substitution

$\Omega_a : \mathbf R[x] \to \mathbf R$
$\Omega_a(f(x)) = f(a)$

then $Ker(\Omega_a) = (x - a)\mathbf R[x]$ and $Im(\Omega_a) = \mathbf R$ therefore the two are isomorphic.

Please help,
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to prove that for _every_ $R$ there is an $a$ such that isomorphism doesn't hold?

Comment: [You start with further clarification of what you mean by "does not apply generally".](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_ring) $\;$

Comment: Also, should the $\simeq\mathbf R^2$ in your displayed equation be just $\simeq\mathbf R$?

Comment: The question seems clear and error-free to me, although I could be mistaken...

Comment: I agree that this needs clarification.  The zero ring clearly needs to be excluded, it should be specified whether the ring may be commutative, and the type of isomorphism should be specified (a priori, the question may have different answers for isomorphisms of rings, $R$-modules, or $R$-algebras).

Comment: I think there are two points to be clarified. First, your $\simeq$ means ring isomorphism or $R$-algebra isomorphism?  Second, you mean such a isomorphism does not hold for all $a\in R$ or for some $a\in R$?

Comment: to clarify all, the question has no typos, the desired isomorphism is the one of rings, and by does not apply generally I mean that you can find a counterexample. rschwieb answered the question to my satisfaction, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $R=\Bbb Q$ and $a=2$, the quotient is a field, while $R^2$ has nonzero zero divisors like $(1,0)(0,1)=(0,0)$. That would be one example that the two are not isomorphic.

One way the isomorphism could hold for all $a\in R$ is if $R$ is a field in which every element had a square root. This happens for the complex numbers, of course, but there are also smaller fields like that.

Comment: Because of nilpotents, it still doesn't hold for $a=0$, or in a field of characteristic $2$.